# FIltering a pandas dataframe with a function defaulting to no filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a python function that filters a pandas dataframe dynamically using default attributes in the function definition. The idea is that if no value is passed into the function, the default value would take over (which I declare as the column itself) and therefore not filter the dataframe at all.

So far I've got this:

```
import pandas as pd

def filter(df, foo="df['foo']"):
    newdf = df[df['foo']==foo]
    print(newdf)

data = {
    'foo': ['First value', 'Second value'],
    'bar': ['First value', 'Second value']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['foo', 'bar'])

filter(df, 'First value')

>>>           foo          bar
>>>0  First value  First value
```

So, the passing of values to filter actually works, but when I run `filter(df)` in order to trigger the default attribute I get an empty dataframe. If I understand correctly, Python is interpreting `"df['foo']"` like a string, and therefore, since there is no value in `foo` that matches that string, it returns an empty dataframe.

I read that I could use `eval()`, but then when I define the function like this: `def filter(df, foo=eval("df['foo']")):` I get a `NameError` saying that `'df' is not defined`.

If I understand right, Python is evaluating the string at the moment that the function is defined instead of when the function is called. Since there is no `df` defined yet, it returns an error.

Is `eval()` not the right tool to use? If so, how should I proceed in order to get all of the rows when no attribute is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

def filter(df, foo="df['foo']"):
    newdf = df[df['foo']==eval(foo)]
    print(newdf)

data = {
    'foo': ['First value', 'Second value'],
    'bar': ['First value', 'Second value']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['foo', 'bar'])

filter(df, "'First value'")
```

Output of `filter(df)`:

```
            foo           bar
0   First value   First value
1  Second value  Second value
```

Output of filter`(df, "'First value'")`:

```
           foo          bar
0  First value  First value
```

Comment: I actually did try that but now I understand that I needed to surround the filtering values with another set of quotes. I was getting EOF errors :facepalm:

Answer (score 3):

May I give you some suggestions:

You could try this one:

```
def filter(df, foo=None):
    if foo is None:
        print(df)
    else:
        newdf = df[df['foo']==foo]
        print(newdf)
```

Also, you could use partial to the function's argument after creating the dataset:

```
def filter(df, foo):
    newdf = df[df['foo']==foo]
    print(newdf)
```

...

```
partial(filter, foo=eval("df['foo']"))
```

Just remember that, after using partial, you need to include the "foo=" keyword